# Finance: replicating portfolio for a European option

Tags: call-options, portfolio

The replicating portfolio for a European call option involves a long position in
A
, while the replicating portfolio for a European put option involves a short position in
A
.

Can you explain why this is the case in general?

Comment: What exactly is unclear? Do you know what the payoffs of a call and put option are?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you know what puts and calls are. Google them and you'll have the answer.